# Including children edges in hierarchical layout without withdrawing them from inside their parents

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

Using Vue.js with mxgraph I'm trying to create hierarchical layout, where vertices are foldable with another vertices as children.
The problem appears when I try to place edges that connects a child with something.
Depending on setting mxHierarchicalLayout.prototype.traverseAncestors parameter true or false it either withdraws the child out of its parent to put it in another place in hierarchy or it doesn't consider this edge as a part of the hierarchy at all and cuts right through anything to reach the destination.

Here are some screenshots to visualize the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5wtZ.jpg

I use 2 different layouts. Hierarchical layout for the children of default parent of the graph and stack layout for their children.

I've already tried working with layout.edgesCache (it's probably edgesSet in documentation), but when the layout has the edge in this set it withdraws it the same way.

//This is the code i use to update the layout

```
var layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph, mxConstants.DIRECTION_WEST);
            var stackLayout = new mxStackLayout(graph, false)
            stackLayout.spacing = 10;
            stackLayout.fill = true;
            stackLayout.marginLeft = 30;
            stackLayout.marginRight = 30;
            stackLayout.marginTop = 10;
            stackLayout.marginBottom = 10;
            stackLayout.allowGaps=true;

            graph.setDropEnabled(true)
            var executeLayout = function (change, post) {
                graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
                try {
                    if (change != null) {
                        change();
                    }
                    graph.getDefaultParent().children.forEach((child)=> {
                        if(child.isVertex()) {
                            stackLayout.execute(child)
                        }
                    })
                    layout.execute(graph.getDefaultParent(), v1);

                } catch (e) {
                    throw e;
                } finally {
                    // New API for animating graph layout results asynchronously
                    var morph = new mxMorphing(graph);
                    morph.addListener(mxEvent.DONE, mxUtils.bind(this, function () {
                        graph.getModel().endUpdate();
                        if (post != null) {
                            post();
                        }
                    }));

                    morph.startAnimation();
                }
            };
```

Expected and actual results are shown in the pictures.